# Problema no Criteria hibernate

Tags: spring-boot, criteria

Estou fazendo um trabalho da faculdade para migrar um projeto spring para spring boot, após seguir [esse tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-migration), porém começou a dar erro no `criteria`.

```
@Repository
public class MessageDAO extends AbstractDAO<Message> implements MessageRepository {

public Message get(Long id) {
    return super.get(id);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Message> getBySubject(String subject) {

    Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(getModelClass());
    criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike("subject", subject));
    criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("date"));
    
    return criteria.list() ;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Message> getBySubjectAndStartDate(String subject, Date date) {

    Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(getModelClass());
    criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike("subject", subject));
    criteria.add(Restrictions.gt("date", date));
    criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("date"));
    
    return criteria.list();
}

@Override
protected Class<Message> getModelClass() {
    return Message.class;
}

}
```

Fica aparecendo erro no

```
createCriteria Cannot resolve method 'createCriteria' in 'Session'
```